# Java interface - Generics

Tags: java, generics

I have two interfaces. An interface A, and interface B, which extends interface A. Now, I have class which likes to keep reference of object that either implements A or B. And I would like to provide setter for it. I tried below, but getting type mis match exception.

```
public interface A {
}

public interface B extends A {
}

public class AB {
private Class<? extends A> object;

public void setObject(Class<? extends A> o){
   this.object = o;
}
}
```

So basically, I would like setObject method to accept an object that either implements interface A or B.

Comment: Just type it as `A`: `setObject(A a)`

Comment: @Jordão Set that as the answer, and include a link describing why that works (polymorphism) for my +1.

Comment: I've just added an FYI answer - everyone's explaining how [bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) work, but totally missed the fact your code is fine, you've just misunderstood the difference between a Class and an Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer:

Type it as `A`: `setObject(A a)`.

A class that implements `B` also implements `A`. Full code:

```
public class UsesA {
  private A a;

  public void setObject(A a){
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

Now, if you really want to work with `B`, you'd type it as `B`, which would also allow you to treat it as an `A`, since `B` inherits from it:

```
public class UsesB {
  private B b; // can call A's methods on this field

  public void setObject(B b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

But now you can't pass an `A` (static) reference to `setObject`. If you really want to do this, then you'd need to first downcast it as a `B`, which could fail at runtime. Generics will not improve on this.

Comment: [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) is a wonderful thing

Comment: @Jordao: Thanks for the answer. But what if in future, interface B adds new method. In which case, I would have to up-cast it, dont't I ?

Comment: To use `B`, you'd have to downcast it, which is not safe. But, if you want to use `B`, you'd type it as a `B`, not an `A`. Remember, a `B` is also an `A`, so you'd still be able to use `A` with a `B` instance.

Comment: Yes, I would have to down cast it. And I agree with you that it is not safe. So, when you say 'type is as B' meaning pass B in setObject, right ?

Comment: @Jordao: That is what confusing me. As per my original question, I would like to have A or B. public class UsesAorB { }.

Comment: @ArjunPatel: But if you want to call a method that only exists on `B`, then you want `B` (and you'll get `A` too, since it inherits from it). If you type it as `A`, you can't call `B`'s methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object implementing `B`, it will also be an instance of `A`.  Because of this, you can make `setObject` accept any `A`, which will allow instances of `A` or `B` to be passed to it.

```
public void setObject(A a){
    this.object = a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't actually match up with your question. You've stated that

> I have class which likes to keep reference of object that either
>   implements A or B

but the field (called `object`) is actually a Class, not an Object (instance of a Class).

*Your code works* if you were truly trying to have your setter accept any interface that extends A. But as you probably realize now from the other answers, you actually want an instance of A :)

```
public class AB {
    private Class<? extends A> type; // renamed from object for clarity

    public void setObject(Class<? extends A> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetter() {
        setObject(A.class); // no errors
        setObject(B.class); // no errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier if you will use (A a) it will work since B is a type of A. Hence child class can always be represents it's parent.